# How to locate title in html head with the title name XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, title

i am trying locate title in html head with the title name XPATH.

i have tried below xpaths but no luck/

i) //contains[@title='Demo Script Test drive - PHPTRAVELS']
ii) //head[@title='Demo Script Test drive - PHPTRAVELS']

i don't want full xpaths

please refer below image as well as this link-

https://phptravels.com/demo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below xpath:

```
//title
```

there are `4 nodes` in `HTML-DOM`, however if you use `//title` in `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//title")` command, it would point to the first node.

Also, you could try the below xpath:

```
//title[text()='Demo Script Test drive - PHPTRAVELS']
```